# Почему у меня не работает CommandBar?

Tags: c#, xaml

```
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Icon="AttachCamera" Label="Attach Camera"/>
            <AppBarSeparator />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Like" Label="Like"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Dislike" Label="Dislike"/>
            <AppBarSeparator />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Orientation" Label="Orientation"/>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
```

У меня этот код не работает(я его взял с XAML Controls Gallery)
вот:
[image: У меня он выдает ошибку.]
А ето с XAML Controls Gallery.
[image: Вот код с XAML Controls Gallery]

> **Как это исправить?**

Comment: А ошибки какие?

Comment: А тип приложения какой?

Comment: WPF aplication.

Comment: Ошибки: XDG0008, XLS0414, MC3074.

Comment: Все дело в том, что эти контролы из WinUI, а он в свою очередь доступны в современных  UWP и MAUI, но не в классических, старых, десктоп проектах (WPF например). Ну и думаю уже догадались, что "как исправить" - это переходить на чет современное.

Answer (score 0):

XAML Control Gallery: открываем и читаем

> Shows all of the XAML controls in an interactive format. This app is the interactive companion to the Fluent Design Guidelines and shows the usage of both UWP Xaml APIs and Windows UI Library APIs.

Т.е. это контролы для приложений UWP и Windows App SDK (WinUI3). Последний тип приложений сейчас рекомендуется Microsoft для создания новых десктопных приложений.

Выберите нужный вам тип приложения, создайте его и уже там контролы будут правильно работать.